# ComboBox not going into proper cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function:

```
Sub AddComboBox(ByVal strName As String, ByVal strTableName As String, ByVal iColumn As Integer, ByVal rIndex As Integer, ByVal cIndex As Integer, Optional ByVal strSetTo As String)
Dim vArr As Variant
vArr = GetTableKeys(strTableName, iColumn)
pos = Application.Match(strSetTo, vArr, False)
Worksheets("C&E Editor").DropDowns.Add(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Left, Top:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Top, Width:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Width, Height:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Height).Select
With Selection
    For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
       .AddItem vArr(i)
    Next i
    .Name = "cmb" + strName
    On Error GoTo setPos
    .ListIndex = pos
End With
Exit Sub
setPos:
    pos = 1
End Sub
```

being called by:

```
AddComboBox "Controller", "controllers", 1, CurrentRowIndex, 3
```

But every time the function is called the ComboBox is added to the correct row, but is always in column 1.

I have a function to add check boxes and is very similar, it uses the same variables `rIndex` and `cIndex` but it puts the checkboxes in the proper columns.

Everything works except the positioning.

The checkbox code is...

```
 Sub AddCheckBox(ByVal rIndex As Integer, ByVal cIndex As Integer, ByVal OnOff As Integer, Optional ByVal caption As String = "")
    Worksheets("C&E Editor").CheckBoxes.Add(Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Left, Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Top, Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Width, Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Height).Select
    With Selection
        .caption = caption
        .Value = OnOff
        .LinkedCell = Cells(rIndex, 14)
        .Display3DShading = True
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: p.s. I have a function to add check boxes and is very similar, it uses the same variables rIndex and cIndex but it puts the checkboxes in the proper columns.

Comment: Is the `C&E Editor` sheet active when you run this? Which module is this code in? Also, is the sheet view set to a zoom other than 100%?

Comment: The zoom is set to 100%, the sheet is active, the buttons to call the functions are on the same sheet.  The calling code is in module A and the functions are in module B, both the addCheckBox and addComboBox are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `xlDropDown` part:

```
Worksheets("C&E Editor").DropDowns.Add(Left:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Left, Top:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Top, Width:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Width, Height:=Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Height).Select
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!!

Comment: Do you know why that fixed it?

Comment: The first argument to `Dropdowns.Add` is the `Left` setting. `xlDropdown` has the value 2 so it ended up on the left of the sheet.